# Vertically align the content in a flexbox child that includes a header and footer

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element, flexbox

I am redesigning my site and have just discovered (!) Flexbox, which is really versatile, and I have been getting to grips with it.

I am using Flexbox to create a row of four items. Each item has a header, content and footer. The content will vary, so Flexbox is very handy because it will adjust to accommodate.

My goal is to have the four items the same dimension, with the header and footer in each aligned horizontally.  The content in each item will vary in size.

I have, after considerable experimentation and reading here and elsewhere, managed to do this using the ::before and ::after pseudoelements to specify the header and footer respectively.

The only problem is that specifying different font sizes as percentages for the content of each item affects the font size of the pseudoelements. Thus if the content font size in Box 1 is different from Box 2 I will have to adjust the value for the header and footer so that they appear the same in each box.

My solution to this is either to specify the font size for the pseudoelements as pixels/ems or to add a  for the header and footer respectively and then target these with CSS. The problem with the latter is that the HTML and CSS are made more complicated.

I have attached the HTML and CSS to illustrate both approaches:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flexbox experiment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Flex_test.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Flexbox experiment</h1>
<p>The goal is to provide four boxes evenly spaced with the same vertical and horizontal dimensions that will change to accommodate varying content.  Each has a header and footer that should be aligned with its neighbour.</p>
<h2>Divs for header and footer:</h2>
<section id="FlexRow1">                     
    <div id="Column1">
        <div id="Column1Header"></div>
        <div id="Column1Content">
        <ul>
            <li>Details 1</li>
            <li>Details 2</li>
            <li>Details 3</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="Column1Footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Column2">
        <div id="Column2Header"></div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div id="Column2Footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Column3">
        <div id="Column3Header"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="Column3Footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Column4">
        <div id="Column4Header"></div>
        <div id="Column4Content">1, 4, 8</div>
        <div id="Column4Footer"></div>
    </div>
</section>
<h2>Header and footer specified as pixels in CSS:</h2>
<section id="FlexRow2">                     
    <div id="Column1">
        <ul>
            <li>Details 1</li>
            <li>Details 2</li>
            <li>Details 3</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    <div id="Column2">4</div>
    <div id="Column3">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Column4">1, 4, 8</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


section > div {
    border: 1px solid steelblue;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*FlexRow 1 */
#FlexRow1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #D4D1EF;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

/* Column 1 */
#FlexRow1 #Column1 {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:10px 10px;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column1::before {
    content:"Column 1 Header";
}

#FlexRow1 #Column1::after {
    content:"Column 1 Footer";
}

#FlexRow1 #Column1::before, #FlexRow1 #Column1::after {
    font-size:80%;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column1Content {
    font-size:90%;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column1Content > ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 0;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column1 li:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column1 li:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 80%;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column1 li:nth-child(3) {
    font-size: 70%;
}

/* Column 2 */
#FlexRow1 #Column2 {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:10px 10px;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column2::before {
    content:"Column 2 Header";
}

#FlexRow1 #Column2::after {
    content:"Column 2 Footer";
}

#FlexRow1 #Column2::before, #FlexRow1 #Column2::after {
    font-size:80%;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column2 > div {
    font-size: 150%;
}

/* Column 3 */
#FlexRow1 #Column3 {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:10px 10px;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column3::before {
    content:"Column 3 Header";
}

#FlexRow1 #Column3::after {
    content:"Column 3 Footer";
}

#FlexRow1 #Column3::before, #FlexRow1 #Column3::after {
    font-size:80%;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column3 > ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 130%;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column3 li:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column3 li:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 80%;
}

/* Column 4 */
#FlexRow1 #Column4 {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:10px 10px;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column4::before {
    content:"Column 4 Header";
}

#FlexRow1 #Column4::after {
    content:"Column 4 Footer";
}

#FlexRow1 #Column4::before, #FlexRow1 #Column4::after {
    font-size:80%;
}

#FlexRow1 #Column4Content {
    font-size:150%;
}

/*FlexRow2 */
#FlexRow2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #ECCCED;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
#FlexRow2 >div {
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-betweeen;
}
/* Column 1 */
#FlexRow2 #Column1::before {
    content:"Column 1 Header";
    font-size: 12px;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column1::after {
    content:"Column 1 Footer";
    font-size: 12px;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column2 {
    font-size:150%;
}

#FlexRow2 #Column1 > ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding:0;
}

#FlexRow2 #Column1 li:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#FlexRow2 #Column1 li:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 80%;
}

#FlexRow2 #Column1 li:nth-child(3) {
    font-size: 70%;
}

/* Column 2 */
#FlexRow2 #Column2::before {
    content:"Column 2 Header";
    font-size: 12px;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column2::after {
    content:"Column 2 Footer";
    font-size: 12px;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column2 {
    font-size:150%;
}

/* Column 3 */

#FlexRow2 {
    margin-top:2em;
    background-color:#ECCCED;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column3::before {
    content:"Column 3 Header";
    font-size: 12px;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column3::after {
    content:"Column 3 Footer";
    font-size: 12px;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column3 {
    font-size:150%;
}

#FlexRow2 #Column3 > ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding:0;
}

#FlexRow2 #Column3 li:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#FlexRow2 #Column3 li:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 80%;
}

/* Column 4 */
#FlexRow2 #Column4::before {
    content:"Column 4 Header";
    font-size: 12px;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column4::after {
    content:"Column 4 Footer";
    font-size: 12px;
}
#FlexRow2 #Column4 {
    font-size:150%;
}
```

1. Are there any disadvantages to my first solution?
2. Is there a better approach?
3. What is the best way to provide a fall-back for browsers that do not support flexbox?

Thanks!

Comment: could you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ of your example to get a better idea of what your trying to achieve.

Comment: New to jsfiddle so here goes: http://jsfiddle.net/agould/yxcadtm5/

Answer (score 0):

You could use on your flex container.

```
align-items: center;
```

this will vertically align everything.

Comment: Thanks Tom but the problem with the relative sizing of the text in the second example remains. I wonder if the best thing is to specify the font size for the header and footer in ems.